# libxl library setup in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, libxl

I am trying to use the library libxl in C++/VS2012. However, I got the error message

> the program can't start because libxl.dll is missing from your
>   computer

I have well followed the instructions for the setup of this library such as adding directory in my project, adding `libxl.lib` in the project dependencies and copying the `libxl.dll` file to the project directory.

I have also tried to install the .dll file with this link http://www.fastwindowstweaker.com/dll-file/libxl.dll-722052.html but it didn't work.

Do you see how can I fix this ?

Comment: How did you link this xl library?

Comment: #include "libxl.h"
using namespace libxl;
in the beginning of my code. This part seems to be working well. I got a problem when executing.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you successfully compiled program. Program can not be started due to `libxl.dll` missing. You can read dynamic-link library search order on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) to find out where you can place dll. Try to put `libxl.dll` near your executable. Than try to use dependencywalker(http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which dependencies not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had exactly the same error yesterday...

Sure you copied the .dll itself and not the .lib? :P

With the .dll inside the project dir it should work. Otherwise you missed something in the configuration steps before, see http://libxl.com/vscpp.html.